# Customizing details page link in BCS list or custom details page redirection with SarePoint 2013

Tags: list, bcs, external-content-type, external-list, bdc

I'm having fun with Sharepoint 2013 and studio 2013, just started dev few months ago -)

I have some external lists pointing to external content type, I would like to redirect to a custom detail  page when I click on one of the list item using one of the selected field value as a URL parameter.

May I do some code with the readItem method of the BCS definition ?

already had a look into the readlist.aspx but I cannot found fields descriptions.

thank you for helping me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the SharePoint Development. You wanna have a custom detail form for the external content, right? For this you can try BCS profile pages. This pages provides the functionality to build and design new pages and fill them dynamically with the external content. This page will shown at the search result as well and looks much better then the default view form!!

I only found a article about BCS profile pages in SharePoint 2010, but they are similar. Have a look!

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-create-a-profile-page-for-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010/

I hope i could help you. Otherwise let me know it!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, I fact it's a bit more complicated -) I already have a page displaying (application page) a lot of contents based on differant data sources. This page is taking a querystring parameter. Now I would like to call this page from the default external list view for a particular external list when I clik on a record. How coud Achive this ?  Thank you for your help